# Outlook 2010 extension of attachment lost

Tags: email, zend-framework, outlook, zend-framework2, email-attachments

We do send emails from our app with xls or pdf attachments to our business clients. Although they do receive the email including the attachment, they are very often not able to open the file, neither pdf or xls (Version Excel5). The file extension is not visible in the email anymore and the clients are not able to right-click and save the attachment.

The email body including attachment is generated with ZF2:

```
$html = new MimePart($content.$this->getSignature());
        $html->type = "text/html";

$xlsAttach = new MimePart($xls);
            $xlsAttach->type = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
            $xlsAttach->filename = $excelFilename;
            $xlsAttach->encoding = \Zend\Mime\Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
            $xlsAttach->disposition = \Zend\Mime\Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
            $body->setParts(array($html, $xlsAttach));
```

I did google already, but without any noteworthy success. As this seems to be a problem with the clients IT infrastructure, there maybe is an experienced IT admin out there or anybody who can take a look at the email header.

The header which arrives is the following:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="=_691d16bb3f9c6766e19e9bcbd8ef1861"
From: XXX
To: XXX
Subject: XXX
Cc: XXX
Sender: 
X-bounce-key: XXX
X-HE-SMSGID: 1dsxY8-0005qz-Hb
X-HE-Virus-Scanned: Yes
X-HE-Spam-Level: +
X-HE-Spam-Score: 1.6
X-HE-Spam-Report: Content analysis details:   (1.6 points)
  pts rule name              description
 ---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
  0.1 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message
  0.7 MIME_HTML_ONLY         BODY: Message only has text/html MIME parts
  0.1 MISSING_MID            Missing Message-Id: header
  0.6 HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG  HTML-only message, but there is no HTML tag
Message-ID: <XXX>
X-HE-SPF: PASSED
Envelope-to: XXX
X-AVK-Virus-Check: AVA 25.14182;7B5CFE
X-AVK-Spam-Check: 1;str=0001.0A0C0208.59BC3F12.007C:SCFSTAT44510583,ss=1,re=-4.000,recu=0.000,reip=0.000,cl=1,cld=1,fgs=0;8389744
```

Comment: Have you tried to look at the full MIME source? You can do that by sending to a Gmail address and then looking at the message source.

Comment: Hi. I at least could reproduce the error in gmail. Even there the file extension is cut off. How to see the message source in gmail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dmitry Streblechenko: Thanks for the hint to Gmail.

Funny thing: My/Our Outlook 2010 adds the correct extension to the attachment received, that's why we never realized the issue on the client side :(. Through sending the Emails to the Gmail Account we saw, that the file extension is actually missing, and not extended while the file was generated. (ever trust your own system)

And, another + for Gmail: We were able to optimize our SPF.